# Saving list against single value in database using django?

Tags: python, django

I have a list of university that i want to store with news id.
My model is this:-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from cms.models.universities import Universities
from cms.models.newsMappings import NewsMappings


class NewsUniversityMappings(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    newsMappingId = models.ForeignKey(NewsMappings, db_column='newsMappingId' ,max_length=11, help_text="")
    universityId = models.ForeignKey(Universities, db_column='universityId', max_length=11, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'news_university_mappings'
```

my views is:-

```
if request.method =='POST':
            university = request.POST.getlist('universityId')
            newsId = 1;
            add_news_university_mappings = NewsUniversityMappings(universityId=university, newsMappingId=newsId)
            add_news_university_mappings.save(using="cms")
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully added to the university list')
```

now, how can i save the university list againt single value of newsid in database.

Comment: Please take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/